# how to share the mobi file to kindle app using intent filter?

Tags: android-intent, xamarin.android

I have implemented a feature to share the files(.MOBI) to other supported apps which are installed in devices using Xamarin Android. I can able to share the files to Drop Box and Google Drive. But not able to share the files to Kindle. I am using intent filter to share the files to other apps. Do we have any other option to share the files to Kindle?

```
Context context = MainActivity.Active.BaseContext;
           Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
           sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
           sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "");
           sendIntent.SetType("application/mobi");
           sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(filepath));
                     if(sendIntent.ResolveActivity(context.PackageManager) != null)
           {
               context.StartActivity(sendIntent);
           }
```